# IBM storage ds3400 Cant connect to management using fiber

Tags: storage, ibm, fiber

i have a problem with a DS3400 IBM storage system we bought a few years back.
when i try to manage the storage using its IBM storage management i cant find it using automatic detection even though its connected directly using the fiber and i can see the Logical drives connected and working properly.

when i tried to connect the two management Ethernet wires and manage the storage directly by entering the IP address manually i am able to connect however after i make several changes to the controller configuration one of the controllers stops responding and i am not able to ping it directly (since you cant make any changes without being connected to both controllers this is a problem) 
whats more bizarre is that when i change the IP of the controller that doesn't respond it starts working ..

i have found some articles over the web explaining stuff about LUN31 being missing and causing similar problems however all my attempts to manually configure it failed .

*link to an example
http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5075711

in short im trying to get my storage to appear in the storage manager when directly connected using only the fiber cable directly attached.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running a production SAN without a support and maintenance contract from IBM? Their support should be able to resolve issues like this in a matter of hours.

Comment: *Update* i have contacted IBM and i have yet to get a working solution to my issue , however this seems to be quite a unique problem from what i gathered after speaking with the storage expert from IBM.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved thankfully
the steps required to solve the issue are 
1) connect the Console cable to the DS3400 storage controller A
Login using the default username / password (shellUsr , wy3oo&w4)
2)enter the command sysWipe and let it finish the reboot cycle
3)connect the cable to the controller B and repeat step 2 
4)Uninstall the IBM storage management software from the machine you are using to manage the storage 
5)reinstall the software (during the reinstall process LUN31 will be created)

hope more people find this useful it took IBM some time to solve this issue in our case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the "right way" is to get LUN 31 to appear once it's been removed, but you can definitely get it to reappear by deleting the storage partition (soft zone) and recreating it.

Comment: sadly .. that didn't work for me.